# Exported pen from Codepen no longer works. What I am missing?

Tags: export, codepen

I'm trying to get this pen `codepen.io/tcorderoIV/pen/dZYRaz` to work in a local environment. But it seems to only work in codepen. I exported and downloaded it. The downloaded code is ostensibly the same as I see in codepen. I'm guessing some file that the code is dependent on is missing.

How can I fix that?

Comment: if you write your file here or put a link to your codepen people can help you better